# ValueError: unsupported format character ‘Y‘ (0x59) at index 146

Tags: python-3.x, valueerror

when using mysql select statements in python,there is  a ValueError pointing that 'Y' (0x59)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for this, and the solutions are as follows

(1) Rrror message: ValueError: unsupported format character 'Y' (0x59) at index 146

(2) Cause: because the sql executed by python has a writing method similar to DATE_FORMAT(CREATE_TIME, '%Y-%m-%d').
Where %Y conflicts with python's parameter %s

(3) Solution: change DATE_FORMAT(CREATE_TIME, '%Y-%m-%d') to DATE_FORMAT(CREATE_TIME, '%Y-%m-%d').

(4) Some friends commented that if the SQL is put into the string and then put into the execution, you need to add another layer: DATE_FORMAT(CREATE_TIME, '%%%%Y-%%%%m-%%%%d')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In your point 3), the pre- and post-change commands are the same, is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone running into the problem that OPs pre- and post-change (point 3) commands are the same:

For me, the solution is to escape the percentage signs using another percentage sign:

```
DATE_FORMAT(CREATE_TIME, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Becomes:

```
DATE_FORMAT(CREATE_TIME, '%%Y-%%m-%%d')
```

[Found here](https://pseudoscripter.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/valueerror-unsupported-format-character-y/)

Excecuting SQL statement in MariaDB with SQLAlchemy engine (through pandas).